# Jenkins file that uses docker-compose gives ambigous error

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-compose

I'm new to Jenkins and I want to automatize my current workflow a little bit. Right now I push it to the raspberry. Then via SSH I pull the changes, run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` afterwards.

My jenkins file is:

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('build'){
            steps{
                script{
                    docker.withTool("default") {
                        sh 'docker-compose build'
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        stage('deploy'){
            steps{
                script{
                    docker.withTool("default") {
                        sh 'docker-compose up'
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when clicking 'build now' I get the following console-output:

```
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (deploy)
Stage "deploy" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: No org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool named default found
Finished: FAILURE
```

I also tried running it with docker.withTool("docker") but that gave me the same results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Docker Commons plugin? https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-commons/

Edit: According to this link for [I would like to use Docker CLI inside of a Pipeline job](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922468-Pipeline-I-would-like-to-use-Docker-CLI-inside-of-a-Pipeline-job)

> You need to make sure that “default” points to a docker tool inside of
>   Manage Jenkins> Configure System which will also run on the os of the
>   slave.

Comment: I have that plugin installed at version 1.16 (it even got installed during the setup process)

Comment: @Cowboy_Patrick I amended my original answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: how would I apply this if I want to use docker compose?